# Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen 'sendKeyEvent method' but it is not helpful because it does not work for windows. Is there another way other than this?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98742
I proposed it here aswell, still waiting for a solution